# JDBC Sybase to MySQL Converter

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I'm trying to convert a Sybase Database to MySQL. I've got an empty String in a Sybase column.If I execute this query in sybase:

```
Select Length(Name) From Adr;
```

i get the result= 0

If i do following in java:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select Name From Adr")
rs.getString("Name").length();
```

I get the Result 1

Can Anyone tell me how i can handle this ?

Thanks Simon

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) say that the resultSet at first is pointing before the first row. So, you code needs to be modified as:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select Name From Adr");
rs.next();
rs.getString("Name").length();
```